# Why a non-root installed software can work across the whole cluster?

Tags: linux, python, cluster, hpc, portable-batch-system

I recently installed a new python3 and another python package locally in my account folder on a cluster with a dozen of nodes (each node with several cores).

I originally thought that I can python3 run my programs only on the node where I installed them, which is presumably the portal node of the cluster, i.e., where I log in. However, I notice that I can actually even submit jobs of such programs running on any nodes on the cluster. I also made sure that I indeed use the newly installed python3.x, not the python2.x already there long before.
This happens on two different clusters (one with PBS job system, the other with LSF Lava).

So why is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Root is generally not required to install software on a unix machine.
It is only required to install it in a global location.

Installing software on a cluster requires the software to be installed in a location shared by all nodes, and in a cluster, typically your home directory is shared.

So installing the software in your home directory will work, as long as only you need it.